# How to use igraph to reshape data by combining common value of two variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, algorithm, grouping, igraph

The sample dataset is as follows:

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 3 |

I want to link the record that with var1 = a to var1 = b, if var2 of var1 = a = var3 of var1 = b.

So that the sample dataset will become something like this:

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 3 |

Also, if the next row after var1 =`b` is also `b`, then the record will also be linked,
for example:

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 3 |
| b | 3 | 5 |
| b | 7 | 9 |
| c | 5 | 9 |

My desired result:

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 5 |
| b | 7 | 9 |
| c | 5 | 9 |

Are there any ways to do this? Thank you!

---

According to zx8754's comment, `igraph` can be used to perform data cleaning for this question. However, when I tried to use

```
library(igraph)

df = structure(list(var1 = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c"), var2 = c(1L,
                                                           2L, 3L, 7L, 5L), var3 = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                                               -5L))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
```

The graph only showed `var2` and ignored `var3`:
[image]

Question

1. How to connect `a` and `b` if their names are not the same?
2. How to add one more variable (var3) in the graph?

Comment: I don't understand, why is the row with `var1 = a` selected? It does not specify any of your conditions (`var2 = 1, var3 = 2`). Aso the columns `var2` and  `var3` are different in the input and output

Comment: @Cettt I think this can be solved using igraph. Question is clear to me. if var1 values are connected via var2 and var3, they collapse.

Comment: https://r.igraph.org/ you mean this package?

Comment: In your second example, all rows are connected to each other, so I'm expecting the first line to be a, 1, 9 (through rows 2, 3 and 5). If there is a condition that the rows have to follow, then i'd at least expect the first row to be a, 1, 5. Why is it not the case?

Comment: @doraemon yes, that link - network analysis

Comment: can you also find a more abstract question title. if this is about data wrangling for igraph, it would be nice if it was findable again

Comment: I am sorry for my poor english... Please give me some time to google it...

Comment: @Maël SInce var3 of row 3 = 5 != var2 of row 4 = 7, therefore row 3 and row 4 will not be connected

Comment: you can use `graph_from_data_frame(df[c(2,3,1)]`, since `graph_from_data_frame` usually takes the first 2 columns as the vertices, and the others are the edge attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(var2 != lag(var3, default = FALSE))) %>%
   summarise(var1 = first(var1), var2 = first(var2), var3=last(var3))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
    grp var1   var2  var3
  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1     1 a         1     5
2     2 b         7     9
3     3 c         5     9
```

Comment: concise and efficient, cheers!

Comment: I guess it may not give the desired output if you try `structure(list(var1 = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c"), var2 = c(1L, 
7L, 3L, 7L, 5L), var3 = c(7L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I believe the use of `first/last` rather than `max/min` should solve the problem

Comment: yes, then issue resolved!

Answer (score 2):

**First of all**: I am skeptical about the feasibility of using `igraph` for your question, since you wanted to separate and group rows sequentially from top to bottom, while `igraph` reads all edge information from your dataframe regardless of the order of rows.

It ***doesn't mean impossible to use `igraph`***, but you may need massive extra effort to retain the sequential feature, e.g., adding edges iteratively and check if they can be linked. I don't think it is worthy with that much efforts since its inefficient and also computationally heavy as well.

---

## Idea

I guess you are grouping the nodes (denoted in `var2` and `var3`) in a ***consecutive*** manner from the dataframe, *top to bottom*. If the the process is interrupted by a row, like from 3rd row to 4th row, then you need to start from a new group.

## Code

Here is an old-school base R option

```
f <- function(df) {
    res <- c()
    repeat {
        if (nrow(df) <= 1) {
            return(rbind(res, df))
        } else {
            for (k in 2:nrow(df)) {
                if (df$var2[k] == df$var3[k - 1]) {
                    df[k, c("var1", "var2")] <- df[k - 1, c("var1", "var2")]                } else {
                    res <- rbind(res, df[k - 1, ])
                    df <- tail(df, -(k - 1))
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you will obtain

```
> f(df)
  var1 var2 var3
3    a    1    5
4    b    7    9
5    c    5    9
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(var1 = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c"), var2 = c(1L,
2L, 3L, 7L, 5L), var3 = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))

> df
  var1 var2 var3
1    a    1    2
2    b    2    3
3    b    3    5
4    b    7    9
5    c    5    9
```

Comment: Does it relate to some computer science algorithms?

Comment: @doraemon I guess not.

Comment: Would you mind to point out which part of your code matches "a" to "b"? Since the real dataset contains 1 million records, so I think it is necessary to include the code that I have mentioned above...

Comment: @doraemon you can take a look at this `df[k, c("var1", "var2")] <- df[k - 1, c("var1", "var2")] `, which updates the current row with the previous if they are linked.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts, however, the solution provided by Onyambu is simpler for me to modify, so I accepted his/her solution. Thank you for your help and time